# Bulk Import of XML Into Existing Tables

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am new to XML and SQL Server and am trying import an XML file into SQL Server 2010. I have 14 tables that I would like to parse the data into. All 14 table names are listed in the XML as nodes (I think) I found some example code that worked with the simple example XML, but my XML seems a little more complicated and may not be structured optimally; unfortunately,  I can't change that. As a basic attempt, I tried to insert the data into just one field of one existing table (SILVX_SN16000), but the Message pane shows "(0 rows(s) affected). Thanks in advance for looking at this.

```
USE TEST
Declare @xml XML

Select @xml = 
CONVERT(XML,bulkcolumn,2) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Kevin_S\Documents          \SilvxInSightImport.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS X

SET ARITHABORT ON

Insert into [SILVX_SN16000]
(
md_group
)

Select
P.value('MD_GROUP[1]','NVARCHAR(255)') AS md_group
From @xml.nodes('/TableData/Row') PropertyFeed(P)
```

Here is a much-shortened (rows removed) version of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SilvxInSightImport Version="1.0" Host="uslsss17" Date="14-09-14_20-40-02">
<Tables Count="14">
<Table Name="SN16000">
<TableSchema>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>PARENT_HPKEY</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE></Column>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>MD_GROUP</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE></Column>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>PKEY</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>NUMBER</DATA_TYPE></Column>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>S_STATE</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE></Column>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>NAME</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE></Column>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>ROUTER_ID</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE></Column>
<Column><COLUMN_NAME>IP_ADDR</COLUMN_NAME><DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE></Column>
</TableSchema>
<TableData>
<Row><MD_GROUP>100.120.25162</MD_GROUP><PARENT_HPKEY>100</PARENT_HPKEY>   <PKEY>161888</PKEY><NAME>UODEDTM010</NAME><ROUTER_ID>10.41.32.129</ROUTER_ID>    <IP_ADDR>10.41.32.129</IP_ADDR><S_STATE>IS-NR</S_STATE></Row>
<Row><MD_GROUP>100.120.25162</MD_GROUP><PARENT_HPKEY>100</PARENT_HPKEY>    <PKEY>278599</PKEY><NAME>UODEETM010</NAME><ROUTER_ID>10.41.4.129</ROUTER_ID>    <IP_ADDR>10.41.4.129</IP_ADDR><S_STATE>IS-NR</S_STATE></Row>
<Row><MD_GROUP>100.120.25162</MD_GROUP><PARENT_HPKEY>100</PARENT_HPKEY>    <PKEY>183583</PKEY><NAME>UODEGRM010</NAME><ROUTER_ID>10.41.76.129</ROUTER_ID>    <IP_ADDR>10.41.76.129</IP_ADDR><S_STATE>IS-NR</S_STATE></Row>
NT_HPKEY>100</PARENT_HPKEY><PKEY>811003</PKEY><NAME>UODWTIN010</NAME>    <ROUTER_ID>10.27.36.130</ROUTER_ID><IP_ADDR>10.27.36.130</IP_ADDR><S_STATE>IS-NR</S_STATE> </Row>
</TableData>
</Table>
</Tables>
</SilvxInSightImport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xPath in .nodes() must specify the whole path to the `Row` nodes so you should start with `SilvxInSightImport` and work your way down to `Row`.

```
/SilvxInSightImport/Tables/Table/TableData/Row
```

In your case you have multiple table nodes, one for each table and I assume you only need one table at a time. You can use a predicate on the table name in the .nodes() xPath expression.

```
/SilvxInSightImport/Tables/Table[@Name = "SN16000"]/TableData/Row
```

Your whole query for `SN16000` should look something like this.

```sql
select T.X.value('(MD_GROUP/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as MD_GROUP,
       T.X.value('(PARENT_HPKEY/text())[1]', 'int') as PARENT_HPKEY,
       T.X.value('(PKEY/text())[1]', 'int') as PKEY,
       T.X.value('(NAME/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as NAME,
       T.X.value('(ROUTER_ID/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as ROUTER_ID,
       T.X.value('(IP_ADDR/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as IP_ADDR,
       T.X.value('(S_STATE/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as S_STATE
from @XML.nodes('/SilvxInSightImport/Tables/Table[@Name = "SN16000"]/TableData/Row') as T(X)
```

You have to sort out the data types used for each column.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22169)

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked great. One other small thing: If I wanted to insert the filename of the source XML (which is found in the element on the second line of the XML) can I include that somehow in the insert statement? This is the element I meant: <SilvxInSightImport Version="1.0" Host="uslsss17" Date="14-09-14_20-40-02">

Comment: @Kevin_S Do you want the value to be `SilvxInSightImport`? If so, you can just add it as a constant in the column list since you already have that value as a constant in the xPath in .nodes(). If the root node can have different names you can change the xPath to use the wildcard `*` in place of `SilvxInSightImport` and use `local-name()` function to extract the node name. Have a look at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22171).